# How to get the first numbers with SED linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

"00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter"
how can i get the first numbers until VGA with SED in Bash script?
Thanks!

Comment: Based on the variation in the answers, you can see that the question is a bit ill-specified. You mention *bash*, so presumably you want to do this from a shell. OK. Is your source data in a variable? … coming from a pipe? … a file? You mention *sed*. Would other tools be OK? You give a single line of input as an example. Unless that  is the only data you will ever process, you should really give multiple examples that span the range of possible inputs (hex?, different trailing texts, etc.). You mention "VGA", but unless that will be a part of every line you parse, it is not a true requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\).*/\1/'
```

will keep the numbers.

In a script you're likely going to pipe the command that returns you the string to sed, like

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter" | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\).*/\1/'
```

which gives

```
00:02.0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ s="00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter"
$ echo $s| sed 's/\(.*\)VGA.*/\1/'
00:02.0
$ echo $s| sed 's/\([0-9]\+:[0-9]\+.*\)VGA.*/\1/'
00:02.0
$ echo $s| sed 's/VGA.*//'
00:02.0
```

or awk

```
$ echo $s| awk '{print $1}'
00:02.0
```

Answer (score 5):

This will also work, but it relies on there being a space after the numbers you want.

```
sed 's/ .*//'
```

Comment: this failed for me with special characters when the input was in `ISO-8859-1`

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '00:02.0 VGA compatible bla bla bla' | sed -e 's/\(^[0-9:\.]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

imho it would be simplier to use awk instead of sed, using awk for what you want would give this:

```
echo '00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter' | awk '{print $1}'
```

much less complicated than using sed, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are parsing *lspci* output. If so, you might want to look into the `-m` option that should be a bit easier to parse. If you are intent on using *sed* with the default output format, then you might be able to do what you want like this:

```
echo '00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter' |
  sed -e 's/\([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]\):\([01][0-9a-fA-F]\)\.\([0-7]\) .*/\1 \2 \3/' |
  while read bus slot func; do 
    echo "bus: $bus; slot: $slot; func: $func"
  done
```

If you are really only reading one line, you could do it without the while loop, but I included it in case you are actually wanting to parse multiple lines of *lspci* output.

Answer (score 1):

```
X="00:02.0 VGA compatible ..."
set $X; echo $1
```

Answer (score 0):

try, `sed -e 's/(^[0-9:.])./\1/' urfile`

Comment: try, 
<code>
cat urfile | sed -e 's/\(^[0-9:\.]*\).*/\1/'
</code>